# How to spin up AWS computing resource on demand within 10 seconds delay apart from using Lambda?

Tags: aws-ec2

Upon user request, my application has to run a CPU heavy application that requires 6 CPU processes. To reduce latency and speed up development, I choose a monolith approach. Therefore, I simply put everything in an 8 cores CPU instead of using event-driven tools like Lambda.

To save server cost, I want my AWS EC2 instance to start only when the end user click "start" on the browser. To maintain a good user experience, I want the delay to be at most 10 seconds.

If I understand correctly, I can choose to use Fargate or EC2. And people say that starting an EC2 or Fargate instances require at least 30 seconds. Is that correct?

Is there any possible solution to dynamically spin up a monolith computing resources within 10 seconds delay apart from using Lambda?

Comment: i m looking same informations about delay